# move_uploaded_file fails -- No error message

Tags: php, file-upload

According to the [PHP.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), if `move_uploaded_file` fails without an error it's because it can't open the originating file, but as far as I can tell the file is present and accessible by the code. Does anyone have any idea what's causing this problem?

Here's the command:

```
    if(!move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],
            SITE_ROOT."/../static/images/photos/tmp/".$fileName.$fileExt)) {
        throw new Exception("ERROR: There was a serious server problem uploading the image :(");
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

Here's where the $newImage is created:

```
if(imagejpeg($img_dst, sys_get_temp_dir()."/tmp.jpg", 100)) {    
    $newImage["name"] = "tmp.jpg";
    $newImage['tmp_name'] = sys_get_temp_dir()."/tmp.jpg";
    $newImage['error'] = 0;
    $newImage['type'] = "image/jpeg";
    $newImage['size'] = filesize(sys_get_temp_dir()."/tmp.jpg");
```

I can even view the file in my system's temporary directory, but even though `filesize()` can see it fine, `move_uploaded_file` seems to be having problems.

The logfiles are empty (aside from a MIME warning: `Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'`). Anyone got any idea what's going on?

---

**Edit**: I wonder if it could have something to do with this?  (From the documentation.)

> **move_uploaded_file()** ensures the safety of this operation by allowing only those files uploaded through PHP to be moved.

Edit: Yes, that was it.

Comment: Argh! I wish I could put a bounty up for this now -- I really need some assistance :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the limitations of `move_uploaded_file`: It can only process images UPLOADED by PHP. As the image I wanted to move was only CREATED by PHP, it would not move it.

I simply replaced the command with `copy`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it has something to do with permission on the folder that you access

Comment: It's not a permissions issue, as I explained in the question.

Comment: this feels like it should have been a comment (by today's standard)

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unlikely that it fails without any errors. Have you checked the error log?

Comment: I did, but I must have missed that part with the log files, sorry. Have you tried chmod() on the file? Might be that there's a permission problem maybe?